# jquery form callback receiving null

Tags: jquery, json

I have a jquery form:

```
var uploadFormOptions = { 
target:        '#ur', 
beforeSubmit:  uploadValidate,  // pre-submit callback 
success:       uploadResponse,  // post-submit callback 
dataType:      'json',
error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
    alert(xhr.status);
    alert(thrownError);
  },
resetForm: true        // reset the form after successful submit 
}; 
$('#upload').ajaxForm(uploadFormOptions);
```

The response function is declared:

```
function uploadResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)  {
```

And it ends up with responseText === null.  The error function is not called.

The script being called is php and definitely returns a value.
I'm at a loss.  Can anyone help?

Thanks.

The only output in the script is

```
if ( is_numeric( $uid["uid"] ) )
      $bool = setcookie("GP_UID", 
                        $uid["uid"], 
                        time()+3600*24*365*10 /*expire: 10 years*/,
                        '/'/*cookie-path*/);
    print json_encode($uid);
```

Comment: responseText `null` is a valid response. Error is only called if the request fails

Comment: I would check that you are sending JSON headers from PHP.. You are most likely sending a plain text / no header...

Comment: Mayhem, does the output I put above constitute sending json headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might need to set response content type as json as below:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```